# Proof of Nonnegativity Inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, inequality, numerical-methods

Prove the Inequality: 
$$\sum_{i,j}\left ( (PAQ)_{i,j}\frac{B_{i,j}^2}{A_{i,j}}-
(PBQ)_{i,j}B_{i,j}\right )  \geqslant 0$$

Given that:

$P$ and $Q$ are $n$x$n$ and $m$x$m$ symmetric matrices,

$A$ and $B$ are $n$x$m$ matrices, and

$A,B,P,Q$ are all non-negative (i.e. all elements $\geqslant 0$) and real.

In the above summation, $1 \leq i \leq n $ and $1 \leq j \leq m$.

Comment: Did you try simply expanding all the multiplications? There will be a lot of indexes, but....

Comment: Well, I have tried partially expanding the multiplications but was unable to further simplify it. I hope there should exist some solution that fits in one page.

Comment: I'm not sure where your formula comes from — it might help to know its origin to know how to prove the inequality.  It looks somewhat like the formula for the determinant of a block matrix (or perhaps a first derivative of that), maybe the difference between two such.  If this is true, then perhaps it is the difference of determinants in which one matrix can be shown directly to majorize the other, perhaps by an application of Cauchy–Schwarz.

Comment: Thanks Theo for your comment. This equation came up in the context of non-negative matrix factorization. I need to show that this entity is non-negative to prove that my algorithm converges. I have numerically tested it and it works.

Comment: Ultimately it will be used to identify cancer drug targets in the Cancer Cell Line Encyclopedia project.

Comment: Does $B_{i,j}^2$ mean the square of the $i,j$ entry of $B$, or the $i,j$ entry of $B^2$?

Comment: Hi Mike, $B_{i,j}^2$ is the square of the $i,j$ entry of $B$. Note that $B$ is not a square matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably $A$ is entrywise *positive*. Let $X$ be the entrywise positive square root of $A$, so that $A=X\circ X$. Let $B=X\circ Y$ for some entrywise nonnegative matrix $Y$. Then the sum in your inequality is the sum of all entries in the matrix
$$
(P(X \circ X)Q) \circ (Y \circ Y) - (P(X \circ Y)Q) (X \circ Y),
$$
which is equal to
\begin{align*}
&\mathrm{vec}(Y \circ Y)^T \mathrm{vec}(P(X \circ X)Q)
- \mathrm{vec}(X \circ Y)^T \mathrm{vec}(P(X \circ Y)Q)\\
=&\mathrm{vec}(Y \circ Y)^T (Q\otimes P) \mathrm{vec}(X \circ X)
- \mathrm{vec}(X \circ Y)^T (Q\otimes P) \mathrm{vec}(X \circ Y)\\
=&\mathrm{trace}\left\{\left[\mathrm{vec}(X \circ X) \mathrm{vec}(Y \circ Y)^T - \mathrm{vec}(X \circ Y) \mathrm{vec}(X \circ Y)^T\right] (Q\otimes P)\right\}\\
=&\mathrm{trace}(ZS),
\end{align*}
where $Z=\mathrm{vec}(X \circ X) \mathrm{vec}(Y \circ Y)^T - \mathrm{vec}(X \circ Y) \mathrm{vec}(X \circ Y)^T$ and $S=Q\otimes P$. Since $S$ is symmetric and nonnegative, if we define $x=\mathrm{vec}(X)$ and $y=\mathrm{vec}(Y)$, then
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{trace}(ZS)
&= \sum_{i<j} (z_{ij}+z_{ji})s_{ij} + \sum_i z_{ii}s_{ii}\\
&= \sum_{i<j} (x_i^2y_j^2-x_iy_ix_jy_j+x_j^2y_i^2-x_jy_jx_iy_i)s_{ij} + \sum_i (\underbrace{x_i^2y_i^2-x_iy_ix_iy_i}_{=0})s_{ii}\\
&= \sum_{i<j} (x_iy_j-x_jy_i)^2s_{ij} \ge0.
\end{align*}